# Question about meaning of "having being said" in this context

Tags: tense, verbs

Do the two paragraphs below mean the same thing, assuming that **having being said to** is the passive of **somebody said to you**

> Having being said to that you are becoming a mother while you are at your husband birthday party would be a great thing.
>
> In my opinion, it is a great thing if somebody, no matter who, ( it could be your mother in law, a friend or an stranger that has just read your blood test ) tells you at your husband birthday oarty that you are becoming a mother.

Comment: **Having being said to that…** is ungrammatical. Can you double-check your source to be sure you've transcribed it correctly?

Comment: Actually this is my original sentence. And what is the correct thing to mean the same thing in sentence number two. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I understand. I just posted an answer that shows some different verb constructions that mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

These sentences all mean the same thing, and they use different constructions for same act of being told:

> (1) **Being told** that you are becoming a mother while you are at your husband's birthday party would be a great thing.
>
> (2) It would be a great thing if **somebody tells you** at your husband's birthday party that you are becoming a mother.
>
> (3) It would be great **to be told** at your husband's birthday party that you are becoming a mother.
>
> (4) It would be great **were someone to tell you** at your husband's birthday party that you are becoming a mother.
>
> (5) It would be great if **someone would tell you** at your husband's birthday party that you are becoming a mother.

If you think knowing the terminology for these would be useful, read on: (1) uses a gerund and the passive voice, (2) uses the active voice and the present tense (within an **if** clause), (3) uses a passive infinitive, (4) uses the active voice, the subjunctive mood in the past tense (though this is debatable), and an infinitive, and (5) uses the conditional mood.